# Origin/master is behind my commit

Tags: git

I am pretty new to git so I have some problems with it sometimes. Today I pushed a commit, but I saw that the origin/master branch is behind my commit. I tried merging but it didn't work. How can I fix that without screwing anything up ?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That either means that you didn't actually push it, or the `origin/master` reference that you have in this checkout is out of date with regard to the `master` branch in the `origin` remote. Running `git fetch` would fix that issue.